# command that lists all the files (in the current directory) that start with an alphabetic , and contain a digit

Tags: unix, grep, command

command that lists all the files (in the current directory) that start with an alphabetic character, contain a digit, and end with a dot followed by a lowercase character then one more character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with grep you can use `ls -1 .|grep -E "^[a-zA-Z].*[0-9].*\.[a-z]+$"`
`ls -1 .`-> show all files in the current directoy (listing one file per line)
.
`grep -E regex`->filter the output
**regex:**
`^` start of line
`[a-zA-Z]`alphabetic character
`.*` any character match-zero-or-more times
`[0-9]`contain a digit
`\.` the dot character
`[a-z]+`lowercase character match-one-or-more times
`$`end of line
"" are very important. If forgot this you're not use regexp, the shell is using globing  characters.